# Convergence of a sequence in a Hilbert space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My problem is the following :

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a Hilbert space and ( . ) the corresponding scalar product. Let $a_1,\cdots,a_M$ be $M$ linearly independent elements of $\mathcal{V}$.
Let $(v_n)\in \mathcal{V}^\mathbb{N}$ a sequence that converges towards $v\in\mathcal{V}$ and that has the following property :

$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \lambda^k_1,\cdots,\lambda^k_M \ge 0$ such that $v_k=-\sum\limits^{M}_{i=1}\lambda^k_i a_i$

I want to prove that the sequences $(\lambda^k_1),\cdots,(\lambda^k_M)$ are convergent and that each limit is $\ge0$

My reasoning is, at the moment, the following : if one of these sequences isn't convergent, since $(a_i)$ is a basis for the set this family generates, then none of the other sequences (and therefore, components) can make up for this divergence or unstability, which would be necessary because of the convergence towards $v$.

Still, this argument doesn't seem solid enough. As always, I'm convinced that the proper justification is obvious and simple, I just don't see it, thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Tell me if the problem seems unclear as is

Answer (score 0):

The main step is to express $\lambda^k_i$ as a continuous function of $v_k$ and $a_1,\dots,a_M$. After that, passing to the limit is straightforward.

In other words, the vectors  $a_1,\dots,a_M$ form a basis for their linear span, and this span contains $v_k$. Thus, you can expand $v_k$ in this basis and observe that the coefficients depend continuously on $v_k$.

More precisely, for every $i$ decompose $a_i=a_i'+a_i''$ where $a_i''$ lies in the linear span of $\{a_j : j\ne i\}$ and $a_i'$ is orthogonal to this span. The linear functional $f(x)=\langle x, a_i'\rangle$ vanishes on all $a_j$ for $j\ne i$. Applying it to the expansion of $v_k$ yields $\langle v_k, a_i'\rangle = -\lambda_i^k \langle a_i, a_i\rangle$. Hence 
$$\lambda_i^k = -\frac{\langle v_k, a_i'\rangle}{\langle a_i, a_i\rangle}$$ which is clearly a continuous function of $v_k$.